# Printing a multilevel container

Tags: c++, vectors

I have these `struct(s)` to keep data about temperature measurement:

```
// data structure representing day 
struct Day{
   vector<double>hour;
   Day();
}; 
Day::Day(): hour(24){
   for(int i=0; i< hour.size();++i) hour[i]=not_a_reading;
}

// data structure representing month
struct Month{
    int month;
    vector<Day>day;
    Month(): month(not_a_month),day(32) { }
};

// data structure representing year
struct Year{
    int year;
    vector<Month>month;
    Year(): month(12) { }
};

// vector holding measured data
vector<Year>yrs;
```

I am trying to write a program to print all the data inside `yrs`. Here is what I got so far:

```
void print_year(ostream os, vector<Year>& v){
for(size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i){
    os << "{year " << v[i].year; 
    for (size_t j=0; j<v[i].month.size(); ++j){
        os << " {month " << v[i].month[j].month;
        for (size_t k=0; k<v[i].month[j].day.size();++k){
            os << '(' <<v[i].month[j].day <<" "<< v[i].month[j].day[k].hour;
            //--^^---- (No << operator matches these operands) WHY?
            os  << ') ';
            }
        os << "}";
        }
    os << "}";
    }
}
```

If I have **one measurement on: 10th of Jan 1992 at 10 o'clock with temperature 61.6 Fahrenheit and two on: 11th and 22th of Feb 1992 with temperatures: 64 and 65.2**. The output (format) will be: (year 1992 { month jan ( 10 61.5)} {month feb (11 64) (22 65.2)})

I'm probably using the `vector access operator[]` wrong.

I was trying to fix it and got to this:

```
void print_year(ostream os, vector<Year>& v){
for(size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i){
    os << "{year " << v[i].year; 
    for (size_t j=0; j<v[i].month.size(); ++j){
        os << " {month " << month_input_tb[v[i].month[j].month];
        for (size_t k=0; k< v[i].month[j].day.size();++k){
            os <<  '('<< k <<" "; // loop counter coincides with day of the month
            for (size_t z=0; z < v[i].month[j].day[k].hour.size(); ++z){
                os << v[i].month[j].day[k].hour[z];
                os  << ')';
        }
        os << "}";
    }
    os << "}";
}
```

}

Then I saw your (Loki Astari) answer and I am writing separate << operators now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try and simplify that each structure knows how to print itself:

```
int main()
{
    Year    year;
    // Load data into year.

    std::cout << year;

    // You can print a vector of years with:
    std::vector<Year>   yrs;

    std::copy(std::begin(yrs), std::end(yrs),
              std::ostream_iterator<Year>(std::cout, "\n"));

    // or a Simple loop:
    for(auto const& year: yrs) {
        std::cout << year << "\n";
    }

};
```

To make this work you need to define an `operator<<` for `Year`

```
struct Year{
    int year;
    vector<Month>month;
    Year(): month(12) { }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Year const& year)
    {
        str << "{year " << year.year;
        for(auto const& month : year.month) {
            str << month;
        }
        str << "}"; 
        return str;
    }
};
```

So the print for `Year` is defined in terms of printing for a `Month` object. So you know have to define how to print a `Month`. Which in turn will print some `Day` objects. So you will also have to define how to print a `Day` object.

The problem you are seeing:

```
os << '(' << v[i].month[j].day <<" "<< v[i].month[j].day[k].hour;
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//    This is a vector.
//    The stream class does not know how to stream a vector.
//    Did you mean `v[i].month[j].month`
```

Comment: so, to reduce the _print function_ to multiple _<< operators_ for each object separately.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis: Yes.

Comment: I updated the question to answer the question at the end. :)